# Getting the JDBC column types

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I need to ask about my column jdbc type in a table, today I am looping throw my columns and then asking about its type, see my code below :

```
public int getColumnDataTypeFromDB(String columnName) {
    int datatype = 0;

    ResultSet columns = null;
    try {
        String schema =
            getMetaDataCatalogName() != null
                ? getMetaDataCatalogName()
                : getMetaDataSchemaName();

        if (TableManagerFactory.isCatalogBasedDatabase()) {
            columns =
                getMetaData().getColumns(
                    schema,
                    null,
                    tableName,
                    columnName);
        } else {
            columns =
                getMetaData().getColumns(
                    null,
                    schema,
                    tableName,
                    columnName);
        }
        //          columns =
        //              getMetaData().getColumns(getMetaDataCatalogName(), getMetaDataSchemaName(), tableName, columnName);
        if (columns.next()) {
            datatype = columns.getInt("DATA_TYPE");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.error(
            this,
            "Error while getting columns information: " + ex.getMessage(),
            ex);
        //return false;
    } catch (DDLCreationException ex) {
        Log.error(this, ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (columns != null) {
                columns.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Log.error(this, ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    return datatype;
}
```

Can I get all the columns metadata in such a table at the same time ?
if yes, how can I do it ??

Comment: Have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters to [`DatabaseMetaData.getColumns(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) are supposed to be a `LIKE`-pattern. So if you want to get all columns from a table, you simply need to pass in `"%"` to the last parameter, `columnNamePattern`:

```
getMetaData().getColumns(null, schema, tableName, "%");
```

Some drivers (also) allow `null` here, but not all drivers do that (the JDBC specification and API documentation is not entirely clear whether that is allowed or not for this parameter)

Answer (score 23):

Use jdbc ResultSetMetaData class to get the detail information of the table columns.

```
 ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("select * from tableName where 1<0");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd=res.getMetaData();
 rsmd.getColumnType(1);
 rsmd.getColumnLabel(1);
 rsmd.getColumnDisplaySize(1);
```

Comment: This will perform better if 0 rows are returned from the query. To speed things up, you should really use "select * from tableName where 1 = 2"

Comment: @lance-java, "To speed things up, you should really use "select * from tableName where 1 = 2" is not an accurate statement because it depends on the database engine executing the query. I've worked with databases that do a full table scan to determine there are no records that satisfy the condition "1=2". I agree that "this will perform better if 0 rows are returned from the query," but it needs to be done in a way that is specific to the engine executing the query.

Comment: Why the `where 1<0`? (or `1=2` from @lance-java)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for data type of column then getColumnTypeName would the one

```java
System.out.println(rsMaster.getMetaData().getColumnName(1));
System.out.println(rsMaster.getMetaData().getColumnType(1));
System.out.println(rsMaster.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(1));
System.out.println(rsMaster.getMetaData().getColumnDisplaySize(1));
System.out.println(rsMaster.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(1));
```